# How to save cassandra data in csv file and check whether its contents are identical?

Tags: java, python-2.7, cql

I want to a python script which execute the cql statement and save the data into actual_ouput.csv file, Once actual_output.csv will be generated then check with expected_result.csv file(Given) whether its contents are same are not?

for eg:

expected_result.csv (/src/test/expected_result.csv)

```
 1110003,0,normal,ced74000-af80
 2000003,0,critical,ced74000-vd93
 4000203,0,normal,ced74000-af91
 6004003,0,critical,309ba800-af9a
```

Now

```
query = """SELECT * FROM {keyspace}.{table};
    """.format(keyspace="mydb", table="Hospital")
    query_result = session.execute(query)
    with open(actual_output.csv, 'wb') as actua_output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(actua_output_file)
        writer.writerows([(row.id, row.p_id, row.conditionrow.data) for row in query_result])
```

The problem in last statemet, always specify the field names. but we don't  want field name associated with row (eg: row.id, row.p_id  etc) so same code will be used for any table.

once data will be successfully save into actual_output.csv file then check whether content of both file will be same.
something like this:

```
asseertEqual(file1, file2)
```

suggest me python script??

Comment: all tables have the same fields?

Comment: No..All tables have some different fields.